# How to query openedx modulestore get_courses

Tags: openedx

I have tried to find the way already on the internet but unfortunately, I am not successful to find it. 
I am trying to query openedx's modulestore to select courses with some criteria.

```
from xmodule.modulestore.django import modulestore
courses=modulestore().get_courses()
```

this how I am using it but now I want to apply some criteria to select courses.